# Why mounting the root filsystem as readonly does not prevent it from changing?

Tags: ext4, readonly

I'm making some experiment with dm-verity and an ext4 filesystem.
Basically, what I want is just to have an ext4 filesystem in read-only that never changes.
I've tried:

- Adding ro,noatime in fstab
- tunefs -O read-only,verity /dev/sda1

Each time the system boot, a couple of bits are changing.
I've tried to troubleshoot this by dumping the system root at each time, this is the output of cmp -l:

```
1073 356 106
1074 163 166
1401  65  71
2045  64  73
2046 233 141
2047  71 226
2048 354 162
```

According to [this](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout#The_Super_Block) website, what it is changing is something in the superblock, in particular:

1. s_wtime
2. s_kbytes_written
3. s_checksum

After a lot of googling I've found [this](https://lists.openwall.net/linux-ext4/2011/05/26/8) e-mail thread where it is discussed the same exact problem, unfortunately without solution.

Do you know how to stop the system to update those fields?

Thank you!

Comment: This looks like a bug, which you might report to LKML.

Comment: Not that this only happens at boot. Also in the thread you mentioned. To me, it looks like a problem in the boot sequence (probably not the kernel). Some important information is missing: your system, are you using systemd.mount, what is the actual mount point for /dev/sda1? The output of `cmp -l` is ok, but I suggest you run `dumpe2fs` before and after to have differences that are more readable. Can you umount `/dev/sda1` while the system is running? That would make debugging easier.

Comment: sda1 is the root filesystem so I cannot unmount it while the system is running.